# Trying to install ncview on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dependencies

The package ncview requires X development headers and headers.

On Ubuntu 12.04 I tried the following command `sudo apt-get install xorg-dev`
and I got the below error message.

This looks like a very long list of packages. Is there something I am missing ?

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorg-dev : Depends: libdmx-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libfs-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxaw7-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcomposite-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxdamage-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxfixes-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxfont-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxft-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxi-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxinerama-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxkbfile-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxmu-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxmuu-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxpm-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxrandr-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxrender-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxres-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxss-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxtst-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxv-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxvmc-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxxf86dga-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxxf86vm-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: xserver-xorg-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score -1):

Quoted from [Ncview on Ubuntu](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_ubuntu.html) (with a couple formatting and capitalization changes):

> Your hint is fine, but you still have to install some packages first:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libxt-dev xaw3dg-dev
> sudo apt-get install libnetpbm10-dev # ppm support
> ```
>
> In addition to this is two links are needed:
>
> ```
> cd /usr/include/X11 ; ln -s Xaw3d Xaw
> cd /usr/lib/        ; ln -s libXaw.so.7 libXaw.so
> ```

You should also install `xorg-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

Continuing with [those instructions](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_ubuntu.html):

> (This looks inconsistent as we mix Xaw3d header with the Xaw lib, but
>   anyway) after that
>
> ```
> ./configure --x-libraries=/usr/X11R6/lib
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> does the job!

Comment: When I type as root user sudo apt-get install libxt-dev xaw3dg-dev -Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libxt-dev : Depends: libxt6 (= 1:1.1.1-2build1) but 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed Depends: